# Stata tabout Continuous and Categorical By Groups

Tags: stata

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
tabout age south race collgrad over(union) using table2.txt
```

How can it be possible to do `tabout` in Stata when you have continuous (such as `age`) and categorical (such as `south` and `race` and `collgrad`) variables?

Comment: I am familiar with this dataset.  The question you're asking appears to be in your last sentence. I still don't understand it but please edit your question to mention what do you want and someone else may be able to help. For reference, `tabout` is community-contributed and not part of official Stata.

Answer (score 0):

please explain your desired outcome, you could just run the following

```
tabout age south race collgrad union using table2.txt
```